# ConcurrentHashMap with add effect

Tags: java

I just tried to get add effect with `ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>` but the elements order is mixed.
Code like a...

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>h=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {           
            h.put(""+Math.random(), ""+i);

        }

        Iterator<String> iterator=h.values().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

... gives in console next values:

```
9
4
6
2
0
5
1
7
3
8
```

... so my question is...

is there a way for ConcurrentHashMap to get original elements order if key is some random string?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a ConcurrentHashMap? Are you going to use it concurrently from multiple threads?

Comment: And is there also a reason why you put double and integer into a <String, String> map?

Comment: @amit you're right. I am interested in multi-threaing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead it will preserve the order of insertion

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

And use

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(mapInstance)
```

See [`Collections.synchronizedMap(mapINstance);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

```
 Map<K,V> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you exactly, You want to preserve order with HashMap ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: He is looking for a *concurrent safe* implementation. `LinkedHashMap` does not provide it.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi Thanks for your reply. I want to keep order with ConcurrentHashMap. Testing with Integer (iterated) key gives positive results but random string keys gives mixed order. So I want to know is there maybe some another optimal way?

Comment: You mean I have not to use ConcurrentHashMap but to use LinkedHashMap + sync map combination instead? Could you show some snippet?

Answer (score 1):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) maintains the order of insertion.

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.